# How to use Moment.js in vuecli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, vue-cli

I have npm installed vue-moment. I need to pass date to p tag via for loop. Also ***I need to create a method*** where i can add number of days to my date so that it will shoe the date after that number of days. How do i do it OR where am I wrong

main.js code:

```
Vue.use(require("vue-moment"));
```

vuecomponent code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>{{ new Date() | moment("MM.DD.YY") }}</span>
    </div>
    <p v-for="data in printdata" :key="data.index" v-html="data.name"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      printdata: [
        {
          name: "paraone"
        },
        {
          name: "<span>{{ new Date() | moment('MM.DD.YY') }}</span>"
        },
        {
          name: "parathree"
        },
        {
          name: "parafour"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  components: {},

  methods: {
    changeDate: function() {
      var todaydate = new Date();
      moment(todaydate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      this.printdata[0].name = todaydate;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.changeDate();
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

The one in div tag is working as expected but how do i get date in second p tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know where I was wrong. I had not imported moment in the script tag of component.
I had to do this

```
<script>
import * as moment from "moment/moment";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      printdata: [
        {
          name: "paraone"
        },
        {
          name: "<span>{{ new Date() | moment('MM.DD.YY') }}</span>"
        },
        {
          name: "parathree"
        },
        {
          name: "parafour"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeDate: function() {
      var todaydate = new Date();
      moment(todaydate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      this.printdata[0].name = todaydate;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.changeDate();
  }
};
</script>
```

and now its working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Install the `moment` library:

```
cd my-vue-cli-project
npm install moment
```

Load it in your `main.js` file:

```
Vue.use(require("moment"));
```

Test it in your `components/HelloWorld.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ today }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as moment from "moment/moment";
export default {
data: function () {
    return {
      today: moment()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! The most complete guide for newbie like me. I change the import part to 
 
`import moment from 'moment'`.  

I don't quite understand why there's so many variation/way.

Answer (score 0):

Vue-moment is Just a set of usefull Vue [filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) for everyday Moment functions.

The *"mistake"* you are doing here is that at-least for Vue 2.0, [filters only work in mustache tags and v-bind](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4352#issuecomment-263976170), not v-html.

In order to accomplish what you are trying to achieve here, you would want to separate the scripting and markup. You can do this in two ways, as I display in your modified code below:

1. Split up the string so you can execute the JavaScript and then convert it back to a string: `"<p>"+ 5*5 +"</p>"`
2. You can also as you tried, use a function to do the job (as you did in `changeDate`)

- I modified your function a bit. Moment defaults to today's date, so no need to get `new Date()`

```js
Vue.use(vueMoment.install);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      printdata: [
        {
          name: "paraone"
        },
        {
          name: "<span>" + moment().format('MM.DD.YY') + "</span>"
        },
        {
          name: "parathree"
        },
        {
          name: "parafour"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  components: {},

  methods: {
    changeDate: function() {
      const todayDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      this.printdata[0].name = todayDate;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.changeDate();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-moment@4.0.0/dist/vue-moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>{{ new Date() | moment("MM.DD.YY") }}</span>
    </div>
    <p v-for="data in printdata" :key="data.index" v-html="data.name"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The error I am getting is the same as earlier. It shows in vscode that moment is not defined

Comment: You did not say anything about moment not being defined in VScode. However, it should work, the issue is only that vscode does not understand that the two files are pathched together in the end

Comment: I figured out the solution. I had to import it where i had called the moment() function.