# "TypeError: moment is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I have installed moment js in my vue project. It's, again and again, giving runtime error

**"TypeError: moment is not a function"**

while it's also giving a compile-time warning

**warning  in ./node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale/locales.js Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression**

I have included it my main.js as `'import moment from 'moment'` and `Vue.use(moment)`

I have also tried including it as `window.moment = require('moment')`

But nothing is resolving the above issues.

In my vue.config.js I have used `new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/)`
 but adding/removing it also doesn't solves the problem.

Comment: 1. Try deleting node_modules 
2. Setup using this link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785212/how-to-use-moment-js-in-vuecli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was due to the unstable momentjs version released. Many people are facing this issue. I hope they'll resolve it asap.

Unstable version: **2.25.0**
Stable version: **2.24.0**

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to figure this out all damn day.

Answer (score 0):

moment.js is not a Vue plugin, so Vue.use(moment) will not work.

you can use it like this in main.js

```
import moment from 'moment'
Vue.prototype.$moment = moment
```

then in your .vue file, you can use it like this

```
this.$moment
```

you can read this [Plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)